# CSS nested (tr,td) color transition times stacking

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this example, I have a table with "Marker" cells, and "Long-press" cells.

My goal:

- Clicking on the Marker cell "marks" the row. Javascript toggles a "marked" class (a gray background and white text).
- Holding a click on the Long-press cell transitions the text and background color over 1 second. In practice I have some javascript that swaps in an editor after the delay, but I've left that out for this example.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the row transition and the cell transition seem to be stacking, though only for the text color (which I'm thorougly confused about). So when I mark the row, the whole row background turns gray in 0.5s, and THEN the text changes to white, and it just looks weird.

If I remove the transition from the long-press cell then the row transition works properly, but then the cell snaps back to default on click-release, and I want it to ease back to normal.

```js
table = document.querySelector('table')
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
 tr = document.createElement('tr')
 td1 = document.createElement('td')
 td1.innerText = 'Marker'
 td1.addEventListener('click', function () { this.parentNode.classList.toggle('marked') })

 td2 = document.createElement('td')
 td2.innerText = 'Long-press'
 
 td3 = document.createElement('td')
 td3.innerText = 'Other cell'
 
 tr.appendChild(td1)
 tr.appendChild(td2)
 tr.appendChild(td3)
 table.appendChild(tr)
}
```

```css
table td { border: 1px solid black; }
table tr {
 transition: 0.5s;
}
tr.marked {
 background: gray;
 color: white;
}
tr td:nth-child(2) {
 transition: 1s;
}
tr td:nth-child(2):active {
 transition: 1s 0.2s;
 background: aqua;
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra transition defined in `tr td:nth-child(2)` that causes the overlapping. Remove this and things should work expected.

```js
table = document.querySelector('table')
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  tr = document.createElement('tr')
  td1 = document.createElement('td')
  td1.innerText = 'Marker'
  td1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.classList.toggle('marked')
  })

  td2 = document.createElement('td')
  td2.innerText = 'Long-press'

  td3 = document.createElement('td')
  td3.innerText = 'Other cell'

  tr.appendChild(td1)
  tr.appendChild(td2)
  tr.appendChild(td3)
  table.appendChild(tr)
}
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr td {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

tr.marked {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}

tr td:nth-child(2):active {
  transition: 1s 0.2s;
  background: aqua;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
</table>
```

Comment: As I said at the end of my post though, now there's no transition when you release the mouse button on the long-press cell. It snaps back to white, and I want it to fade from blue to white.

Comment: Okay well that does look better. I suppose there's no way to have the long-press animation in particular have a different transition time than the full row animation?

Comment: seems if there be a different one, it would override the row transition. May be can be achieved if we are to combine this some JS